# What is OptimisedImplicitBlockRepeating component type in FIX?

Tags: fix-protocol

According to [FIX specification](http://fiximate.fixtrading.org/en/FIX.5.0/components_sorted_by_type.html) there are only two FIX components of `OptimisedImplicitBlockRepeating` type:

- `InstrmtLegGrp`
- `UndInstrmtGrp`

However, this type doesn't seem to be documented anywhere. What's the difference between `OptimisedImplicitBlockRepeating` and normal `ImplicitBlockRepeating`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the author](http://forum.fixtrading.org/t/what-is-optimisedimplicitblockrepeating-component-type-in-fix/239) of this concept it means that FIXML representation of such tags eliminates component nesting. For example instead of `<Leg><Leg ....></Leg></Leg>` elements are inlined into `<Leg ..../>`.